# Dynamically change layout of Angular 2/5 application according to config file

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular5

I'm trying to come up with a way of flexible layout, which will function like so.

1. There is a default layout of elements on the page (such as inputs, tables, etc).
2. User can change where any of those elements will appear on his screen. He can move a certain input to a different location inside a component. I then make a request to the back-end and save his configuration.
3. Whenever user logs in again, the config is loaded via HTTP request and default view is altered in accordance with the config.

An example of my current code:

```
    <div class="row row-mp docDefaultRow">
        <div>
        <ng-template #firstContainer>

        </ng-template>
        <!--<app-partner-recipient -> this is the component that gets created in firstContainer
                [areItemsSet]="areItemsSet"
                (selectedPartnerEmitter)="setPartnerFromChild($event)"
                (selectedRecipientEmitter)="selectedRecipient"
                [partnerMissing]="partnerMissing">
        </app-partner-recipient>-->
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="date_created">Datum dokumenta</label>
                        <form #myForm="ngForm" novalidate>
                            <my-date-picker name="date_created"
                                            id="date_created"
                                            [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
                                            [disabled]="true"
                                            [ngModel]="date_created"
                                            required readonly>
                            </my-date-picker>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #secondContainer>

    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #thirdContainer>

    </ng-template>
```

And in the component

```
@ViewChild('firstContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container1;
@ViewChild('secondContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container2;
public component1Ref: ComponentRef<any>;
public component2Ref: ComponentRef<any>;
public config;

ngOnInit() {
    this.createComponents(this.config);
}

createComponents(cfg) {
    // How to use config to create components in different places?
    this.container1.clear();
    const factory1: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PartnerRecipientComponent);
    this.component1Ref = this.container1.createComponent(factory1);
    this.component1Ref.instance.areItemsSet = this.areItemsSet;
    this.component1Ref.instance.partnerMissing = this.partnerMissing;
    this.component1Ref.instance.selectedPartnerEmitter.subscribe(event => this.setPartnerFromChild(event));
    this.component1Ref.instance.selectedPartnerEmitter.subscribe(event => this.selectedRecipient = event);

    this.container2.clear();
    const factory2: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ItemsComponent);
    this.component2Ref = this.container2.createComponent(factory2);
    this.component2Ref.instance.itemsMissing = this.itemsMissing;
    this.component2Ref.instance.isPartnerSet = this.isPartnerSet;
    this.component2Ref.instance.selectedPartner = this.selectedPartner;
    this.component2Ref.instance.selectedPremiseId = this.selectedPremiseId;
    this.component2Ref.instance.ItemsArrEmitter.subscribe(event => this.refreshItems(event));
    this.component2Ref.instance.documentSummaryEmitter.subscribe(event => this.refreshDocumentSummary(event));
    this.component2Ref.instance.temporaryItemsEmitter.subscribe(event => this.temporaryItems = event);
    this.component2Ref.instance.arePricesUpdated.subscribe(event => this.pricesUpdated(event));
}
```

What I don't know, basically, is how to create component in any ng-template I want, according to the config file, i will recieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think i kind of brute-forced the whole thing. What I did was restructure what were child components and made them emit values via services to which i subscribe in any component that includes them.

Then i retrieve a config file and make it a behaviorSubject, available for subscription.

I subscribe to cfg, and process the emitted values like so:

```
this.config.forEach(component => {
            if (component === 'partnerComponent') {cfg.push(PartnerRecipientComponent);
            } else if (component === 'itemsComponent') {cfg.push(ItemsComponent);
            } else if (component === 'summaryComponent') {cfg.push(OrderSummaryComponent);
            } else if (component === 'dateComponent') {cfg.push(OrderDateComponent);
            } else if (component === 'numberComponent') {cfg.push(OrderNumberComponent);
            } else if (component === 'methodComponent') {cfg.push(SendingMethodComponent);
            } else if (component === 'remarkComponent') {cfg.push(OrderRemarkComponent);
            } else if (component === 'timepickerComponent') {cfg.push(TimepickerComponent);
            } else {cfg.push(undefined); }
        });
        this.createComponents(cfg);


createComponents(cfg) {
    const containers = [this.container1, this.container2, this.container3, this.container4, this.container5, this.container6, this.container7, this.container8, this.container9, this.container10];
    for (let i = 0; i < cfg.length; i++) {
        if (cfg[i] === undefined) {continue; }
        containers[i].clear();
        const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(cfg[i]);
        this.componentsArray.push(containers[i].createComponent(factory));
    }
}
```

and create components.